# How to find the curvature and torsion of $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=\frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

**Question:** Assume that $\gamma:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular curve and $|\gamma(t)|\neq 0$ for all $t\in(a,b)$. What can we say about the regularity of $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=\frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|}$? Then, compute curvature and torsion of $\tilde{\gamma}$ in terms of those of $\gamma$.

**What did I do:** We know that $\tilde{\gamma}(t)$ is a curve lies on the unit sphere. Also, $$\tilde{\gamma}'(t)=\frac{\gamma'(t)|\gamma(t)|-\gamma(t)|\gamma(t)|'}{|\gamma(t)|^2}=\frac{\gamma'(t)|\gamma(t)|^2-\gamma(t)\langle\gamma'(t),\gamma(t)\rangle}{|\gamma(t)|^3}$$ Then I assume that $\tilde\gamma'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0\in (a,b)$ and find $$|\gamma'(t_0)|\cdot|\gamma(t_0)|=\lvert\langle\gamma'(t_0),\gamma(t_0)\rangle\rvert$$ which is equality case of Schwarz inequality. Then there exists a scalar $k$ such that $\gamma(t_0)=k\cdot \gamma'(t_0)$. However, if we put it into the $\tilde\gamma'(t_0)=0$, we can find a contradiction.

**Edit:** Because I make a mistake while calculating, the contradiction is not valid anymore. $\tilde\gamma'(t)=0$ if $\gamma(t)=k\gamma'(t)$ for some scalar $k$.

But what can I do for the calculate curvature and torsion except calculating tons of complicated derivatives?

Comment: You have the quotient rule wrong. But I recommend that you write
$$\gamma = |\gamma|\tilde\gamma$$ and do you differentiation with this equation to solve for $\tilde\gamma'$ and $\tilde\gamma''$. You might start out assuming $\gamma$ is arclength-parametrized so that the Frenet equations will be easier to work with.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right, I wrote "+" instead of "-".  Because $$\frac{d}{dt}|\gamma(t)|^2=2|\gamma(t)||\gamma(t)|'$$ and $$\frac{d}{dt}<\gamma(t),\gamma(t)>=<\gamma'(t),\gamma(t)>+<\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)>=2<\gamma'(t),\gamma(t)>$$ and $|\gamma(t)|^2=<\gamma(t),\gamma(t)>$, $$|\gamma(t)|\cdot |\gamma(t)|'=<\gamma'(t),\gamma(t)>\implies |\gamma(t)|'=\frac{<\gamma'(t),\gamma(t)>}{|\gamma(t)|}$$ So, I did not see what is wrong with the identity.

Comment: @Masacroso After correcting $+/-$ mistake, If we check for $\gamma(t)=k\cdot \gamma'(t)$, we can see that $\tilde\gamma'(t)=0$ (If I did not make a mistake again :D ) So, If $\gamma(t_0)$ and $\gamma'(t_0)$ are linearly dependent at some $t_0$, $\tilde\gamma'(t_0)=0$ and new curve is not regular. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lecdabster sorry, I think I was wrong, it seems possible that $\tilde \gamma '(t)=0$ for some $t$